# fade out <a href> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

I'm trying to face a particular class `.mosaic-block` to fade on clicking this:

```
<a href="#">
  <div id="t0" class="n0 lfloat"><img src="images/home.png"><br>Home</div>
</a>
```

My Jquery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('a #t0').click(function() {
  $(".mosaic-block").animate({ 
        opacity: 0.0
        }, 1500 );
    }); 
});
</script>
```

But I'm not getting the desired results.

**EDIT#1**
My `.mosain-block` `HTML` code:

```
<div class="mosaic-block bar">
    <h4>Sloppy Art</h4>
    <p>abcd</p>
</div>
```

Comment: so what result are you getting?

Comment: I see no element with class mosaic-block in the HTML.

Comment: And just to be sure, because your selector is strange, do you have other elements with id t0 ? Because an id can only be used once.

Comment: @dystroy: I've not posted my entire `HTML` code.

Comment: [your code works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jve7P/).

Comment: @dystroy: Really sorry, I forgot to load the `jquery.js` file .:P. Please add your answer so I can mark it correct.:)

Comment: You shouldn't have block elements inside an anchor. This is an HTML4.01 specification. Or that anchor's existence is just there to make the cursor a pointer, use a div and css.

Comment: @popnoodles Block-level anchors are now allowed in HTML5 and are actually working in any browser due to earlier implementations of that behavior through the vendors.

Comment: They've always worked. We don't know if this is 4 or 5 but it's nice that they are allowed in 5. It still feels dirty tho!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine.

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jve7P/).

So the error is elsewhere. For example in the jQuery import (*yes, I got a hint on this one ;)* ) which could look like this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I misspelt the file name while loading the `jquery.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the inbuilt [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method

```
$(".mosaic-block").fadeOut(1500);
```

Comment: Not necessarily since fading out will affect the layout `display:none`..  Animating the opacity only affects the visibility.